# Publishing an SSR app w/ Angular 17 on a cPanel is possible, right?

Tags: angular, apache, deployment, cpanel, server-side-rendering

When I build my Angular 17 SSR project with `ng build`, I get this:

```
  ├── dist
  │  └── my-project
  │    ├── .DS_Store
  │    ├── 3rdpartylicenses.txt
  │    ├── browser
  │    │  ├── .DS_Store
  │    │  ├── assets
  │    │  │  ├── ...
  │    │  ├── chunk-5XNHKK4I.js
  │    │  ├── ...
  │    │  ├── favicon.ico
  │    │  ├── index.html
  │    │  ├── main-OTXGCZUU.js
  │    │  ├── media
  │    │  │  └── ...
  │    │  ├── polyfills-RT5I6R6G.js
  │    │  ├── styles-6I36XN7I.css
  │    ├── prerendered-routes.json
  │    └── server
  │      ├── chunk-2VXXU7NI.mjs
  │      ├── ...
  │      ├── index.server.html
  │      ├── main.server.mjs
  │      ├── polyfills.server.mjs
  │      ├── render-utils.server.mjs
  │      └── server.mjs
```

Now my question is: How do I publish this to my cPanel / Traditional hosting provider?

I imagine that Angular made it easy for deploying SSR on Firebase, and other mainstream cloud services, but what about local cloud services using cPanel?

Dragging and dropping the /dist into the /public_html folder in the cPanel. Not the solution